# Android tablet not connecting to Wi-Fi while previously did

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have three devices:

1. Tablet running Android 2.2; (WPAD)
2. Tablet running Android ICS; (Samsung Tab 2)
3. A laptop. (Dell Studio 1558)
4. Wirelss Router: WRT120N (Linksys)

Wireless Router access is protected with WPA/WPA2 PSK. I can confirm that password given is correct.

My laptop <sup>(3)</sup> and Android ICS tablet <sup>(2)</sup>, both connect fine to the wireless router.

But my other tablet <sup>(1)</sup> doesn't connect, it keeps "Scanning" and then disconnects. This tablet used to connect to router earlier, but now it does not. I have also observed that after a few seconds the wirless network is shown as "Not in Range, secured with WPA/WPA2 PSK" and then comes back with message "Remembered, secured with WPA/WPA2 PSK". So I am also not sure whether it is the problem with the tab!

Android ICS <sup>(2)</sup> is my new Samsung tab 2 tablet, so I have no idea whether this is caused due to new connection or not? To ascertain this, I have tried connecting only the first tablet <sup>(1)</sup>, but still not working :(

The wireless router is connected to ADSL router provided by service provider. The ADSL router settings are password protected, i.e I cannot view ADSL router settings through web browswer.

Any thoughts on what could be causing the tablet to be losing the connection?

Comment: Try changing the mode, channel, frequency and security.

Comment: Exactly what tabs are we talking about here?

Comment: @roxan: How and where do I change channel, frequency and security?. I have updated my post to mention that the ADSL router settings are password protected. I only have access to my wirless router. Do you mean these settings are of wireless router?. thanks.

Comment: Yes on wireless router.

Comment: @roxan: Sorry for being dumb. I do not correctly understand what is channel, frequency and security. Could you please let me know what these settings should contain and to be set to ?

Comment: @pradeeptp does that behaviour persist -- or does the tab connect if you just wait a while? I encountered the same problem after updating my HTC Buzz to 2.3 -- sometimes I have to wait up to 30min, but it always solves finally.

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved this issue myself. Here is what I did to resolve it:

1. Accessed wireless router's settings. Please remember I do not have access to ADSL router which is connected to the internet.
2. The linksys wireless router setting has "Wireless" menu. Under this menu, click on "Wireless MAC Filter".
3. Click on "Enabled" radio button.
4. Click on "Prevent listed computers from accessing the wireless network" radio button. I saw a list of MAC addressed in this list. One of the MAC addresses was that of the tablet which was not connecting. I removed this from this list and VOILA!!!! my tab was happy :)

(I still don't know how it got into this list!!)

Comment: Please mark the question as answered then

Answer (score 1):

My Nexus 10 recently stopped connecting to the internet via WiFi after it had been connecting for 3 months. I simply rebooted off my wireless router by removing the power for 30-60 seconds and then powering up. Once the router rebooted, presto, my Nexus 10 was once again connected to the wireless network and the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

many Android 2.2 users report the same issue<sup>1</sup>. I'd recommend trying:

- Delete the network from known list and then reconnect

AND/OR

- Set a static IP address for your 2.2 device: wifi settings -> menu -> advanced -> use static IP (depending on your network config, submask to use: 255.255.255.0, default gateway (router IP): 192.168.1.1) to something like 192.168.1.200

--

<sup>1</sup>See the original authors:
  http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile/bbo7Y3CPOn8%5B1-25%5D

Comment: I have tried this settings but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Someone with access to that router may have accessed it through the internet just as you did and set up the MAC filtering. You have to manually enter every MAC address of every device that is running on your network in order to block just one MAC address or multiple addresses. Then you have to set what MAC address to block and save those settings just as you did to unblock your MAC address on that specific device.

Comment: Your statements are very confusing. Please re-read it, and edit. Which ones should they block or unblock?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem twice, once with my HTC Flyer, originally with Android OS 2.3, but somehow after I updated OS to Gingerbread the problem's gone.
Second happened with my Google Nexus i515, running OS 4.04. Tried everything until i clicked Settings -> System -> Change wifi regulatory domain, and chose EMEA and Rest of World (the other options were US & Japan which weren't where I'm located) wifi settings resetted & problem's solved.